# What is the best TCP congest algorithm to use for a mobile device?

Tags: networking, performance, tcp, performance-tuning, mobile-devices

Given the multitude of TCP algorithms available now and the rise of Linux based mobile devices, what are ideal algorithm(s) to consider?

From reading of the various implementations, Veno and Westwood+ look interesting but I am interested in hearing about real data.

Comment: This is technically off topic.  But I am not going to vote to close because linux tcp algorithms for high latency (and probably higher packets loss) is relevant to system administration.

Comment: as an sysadmin I see it is quite relevent as to planning and executing any scale VPS servers with KVM or any hypervisor up to and including DSs.

Answer (score 3):

[TCP Veno: TCP Enhancement for Transmission Over Wireless Access Networks](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.2.1469&rep=rep1&type=pdf) contains several tests of TCP Veno over wireless networks and the experiments show that Veno gets better throughput when there is a good amount of random packet loss. The experiments seem quite thorough to me, multiple tests throughout the day in disperse geographic locations.

According to [TCP Congestion Control Over 3G Communication Systems: An Experimental Evaluation of New Reno, BIC and Westwood+](http://www.informationweek.com/whitepaper/Wireless/wp100839;jsessionid=42PFCGPKEWEZTQE1GHPSKH4ATMY32JVN?articleID=100839) (which you can get by registering with information week, all those performed roughly the same.

All that being said, my android is currently set to cubic (latest cyanogen) so I am going to have a go with veno :-)

Comment: I will try it on my own PC-box (gentoo) and see if it works as well.